# Exposing commands from docker container to main shell

Tags: docker, command-line, docker-container

I was wondering if can I somehow expose outside of the container some its internal command.

Like for example we have [this](http://%20https://store.docker.com/community/images/mkenney/npm) image.
We run container on that. And the aim is to have the possibility of using commands which are inside of that container like `npm`, `node` etc. outside in our shell.

Going more deeply I want to prepare developer environment where you don't need to have installed even `node` or `npm` on your PC. Just simply pull dockers, run it and use necessary commands.

Is it even possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. The trick is to mount your volume inside the container. For example `docker run -v ${PWD}:/src mkenney/npm:latest npm`

Full example:

```
docker pull mkenney/npm:latest
docker run --rm -it -v ${PWD}:/src mkenney/npm:latest npm init
# Complete your npm init questions
docker run --rm -it -v ${PWD}:/src mkenney/npm:latest npm install --save express
cat package.json
# You will see your package.json file
```

But it is too long to type every time. You could create an alias.

```
alias mynpm='docker run --rm -it -v ${PWD}:/src mkenney/npm:latest npm'
mynpm list
# You will see the list of your package.json
```